# c# socket server dont work correct in Ubuntu(linux)

Tags: c#, sockets, ubuntu, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want have worker service in asp.net core for socket server 
In first run it's okay get client messages.
but in second run I get first client message but i cant get second message 
when i reconnect again I get first client message but i cant get second message 
this happened in Ubuntu and I windows work perfect in all runs 
worker service is like this

```cs
public class DeviceConnectionWrokerService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly TcpListener _listener;
    private bool _running = false;

    public DeviceConnectionWrokerService()
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 6000);
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _listener.Start();
        _running = true;
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var client = await _listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
            _takeCareOfCleint(client);
        }
    }

    private async void _takeCareOfCleint(TcpClient client)
    {
        NetworkStream stream = null;
        StreamReader reader = null;

        string clientEndPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();

        try
        {
            stream = client.GetStream();
            reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            char[] buff = new char[64];

            while (_running)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("*** Ready to read");

                int nRet = await reader.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Returned: " + nRet);

                if (nRet == 0)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Socket disconnected");
                    break;
                }

                string receivedText = new string(buff);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("*** RECEIVED: " + receivedText);
                Array.Clear(buff, 0, buff.Length);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception excp)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(excp.ToString());
        }
    }

    public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _listener.Stop();
        _running = false;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

please help me

Comment: Do you want to disconnect?  TCP you can get a message with zero bytes so you should not disconnect (nRet == 0).  Also the operating system probably is sending back a different return character than windows.

Comment: no in after i send first message in console I see  "*** RECEIVED: ****" and  this "*** Ready to read" when i check with break point come to this line and stop ```int nRet = await reader.ReadAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length);``` for second  try to get

Comment: Why do you keep opening the streams?  The stream should be opened once when the client is constructed and leave it opened.

Comment: I check it dont work this code perfectly work in my windows machine

Comment: Doesn't matter.  The drivers could be different an may on work machine and not another.  A stream should not open and close in the middle of a connection.  You could loose data.

Comment: thanks I compliance in my production code